# Select Feature shows outline not filled

Tags: arcgis-10.0, c#, arcgis-engine

```
public static void SelectBy(this IActiveView view, ILayer2 targetLayer, 
    string filterClause, esriSelectionResultEnum selectionResult ) {

    IFeatureSelection featureSelection = targetLayer as IFeatureSelection;
    if ( featureSelection == null ) return;

    IQueryFilter queryFilter = new QueryFilterClass();
    queryFilter.WhereClause = filterClause;

    IColor selectColor = featureSelection.SelectionColor;
    selectColor = Local.ColorToIColor( System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed );
    featureSelection.SelectionColor = selectColor;
    view.PartialRefresh( esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGeoSelection, view.FocusMap, null );

    featureSelection.SelectFeatures( queryFilter, selectionResult, false );
    ISelectionSet selectionSet = featureSelection.SelectionSet;
    view.PartialRefresh( esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGeoSelection, view.FocusMap, null );
}
```

If I use this code to make a selection calling it with:

```
view.SelectBy( layer, "[KeyField] = 10000.0",   
    esriSelectionResultEnum.esriSelectionResultNew);
```

My feature polygons are always FILLED. If I set the featureSelection.Symbol field to a SimpleLineSymbol (and set SetSelectionSymbol=true) it shows nothing. How do I do a feature selection that is NOT filled (as happens when I use IMap.SelectByShape()?)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void SelectBy( this IActiveView view, ILayer2 targetLayer, string filterClause, esriSelectionResultEnum selectionResult ) {
    IFeatureSelection featureSelection = targetLayer as IFeatureSelection;
    if ( featureSelection == null ) return;
    IQueryFilter queryFilter = new QueryFilterClass();
    queryFilter.WhereClause = filterClause;
    IColor selectColor = Local.ColorToIColor( System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed );
    ISimpleFillSymbol fillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbolClass();
    fillSymbol.Color = selectColor;
    ISimpleLineSymbol outlineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbolClass();
    outlineSymbol.Color = selectColor;
    outlineSymbol.Width = 2;
    fillSymbol.Outline = outlineSymbol;
    fillSymbol.Style = esriSimpleFillStyle.esriSFSHollow;
    featureSelection.SelectionSymbol = fillSymbol as ISymbol;
    featureSelection.SetSelectionSymbol = true;
    featureSelection.SelectFeatures( queryFilter, selectionResult, false );
    view.PartialRefresh( esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGeoSelection, view.FocusMap, null );
}
```

This works. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Not really.. this solution is just about the simplest hollow polygon fill as it gets.

Comment: Is it a quirk of using ArcEngine that the default selection symbol is a solid fill? I have never seen that happen in ArcMap.

Comment: Does anyone know what the "default selection symbology" is? (It must have something to do with this because I noticed that after I ran the previous code even the SelectByShape() calls were using a filled selection. Using ILayerDescription can I set this one for the whole layer (and thus remove the symbol definition from the above code? - Of course, what actions would reset the default selection?)